# How to attach an armature to a model?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm trying to get this rectangle to move based on the armature inside of it but it's not working.

Everything I've read told me to select both the armature and the model and then parent with automatic weights but nothing happens when I do that, not even an error comes up.

How do I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you going into pose mode to move your mesh? Add some pictures so we have a better idea.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue, because as it stands it is not answerable at the moment. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button under the post. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: @Relevred Yes I've been going into pose mode. Also sorry about before, I've added some screenshots to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: hello,it's hard to guess, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you did *With Automatic Weights*? It really looks like you parented the armature to the cube, with the cube as the parent. That's wrong. The cube must be the child.

Make sure you select the objects in the correct order. The so-called *active* object is displayed *orange*. The so-called *selected* objects are displayed *red*.

The cube must be the child (=red), selected first in the viewport. The armature must be the parent (=orange), selected last. After you parented them *With Automatic Weights* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in *Object* mode) you will see the hierarchy in the outliner. The armature is in the collection, and when you expand the node you will see the cube.

[image: selected and parented objects]

In *Pose* mode you can deform the mesh.

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed the issue!!